# Navigation bar wont fit the top and block links deform

Tags: html, css, web

**Navigation bar problem**
I could not make the navigation bar have a margin of zero so that it would fit the top completely. I tried by retyping some css and setting padding to zero.
However I had no luck with such action.

So i thought Why not set the margin to `-8` ? Well now the blocks on the right don't seem to fit.... Ugh. My result looks like this: [Online screenshot](https://gyazo.com/30acb8abf37593e7ee3633f4e2eef4dd)

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="grafik_designs">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="tip_of_the_week.php">Inventions</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="blog.php">Timeline</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="index.php">Quotes</a></li>

  <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
    <li><a href="login.php">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #525252;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: -8px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #4A4747;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #282828
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #282828;
}

#big_field {
  background-color: #847F7F;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 320px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 110%;
}

h1 {
  color: 283926;
}

#anders {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 850px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the width of the `body` to 100% and remove any `margin` and `padding`. Now the `ul` fills the whole width: https://jsfiddle.net/gyddu6o0/

```
body {
background-color: #525252;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size:16px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #4A4747;
border-radius: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markup has a few problems, the first `ul` is not closed so the next elements is it's child. For what you are trying to achieve i would wrap the ul's in a `nav` element.

The markup should look like this

Here is an [**Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/8deqgt8x/)

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="grafik_designs">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="active" href="tip_of_the_week.php">Inventions</a></li>
      <li><a class="active" href="blog.php">Timeline</a></li> 
      <li><a class="active" href="index.php">Quotes</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul style="float:right;list-style-type:none;">
      <li><a href="login.php">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
        body {
    background-color: #525252;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .nav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #222;
  }

  ul {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #4A4747;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }

  li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  }

  li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
  }

  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #282828
  }

  li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #282828;
  }

  #big_field {
    background-color: #847F7F;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 320px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 110%;
  }

  h1 {
    color: 283926;
  }

  #anders {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 850px;
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
```